# How to limit insertion of child records to N records?

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am using Oracle database. 
I have two tables, let's say Table A and Table B. They have 1:N relationship between them. I need to limit the 'N' to a specific number such as 10. I will additionally need that nth number for every inserted record as well.

The data is inserted through a Java application which is deployed on multiple nodes.

Tables B looks something like(ForeignId will be primary key of Table A):

```
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
| Id |   Data   | UniqueId | ForeignId |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
|  1 | Somedata |        1 |         1 |
|  2 | Somedata |        2 |         1 |
|    |          |          |           |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
```

Solution I have come up with:

- I have made a composite key (UniqueId,ForeignId) with unique
  constraint.
- Turned auto-commit on.
- The value of UniqueId is calculated by a select statement while
  the data is inserted.
- If we get a unique constraint exception, we retry.
- If the value of UniqueId > 10, we delete the row and roll back.

This solution has worked so far but I feel  there must be some better way of achieving this.

Am I over-engineering this?

Comment: sample data and expected output would be helpful

Comment: Firstly, is this Oracle or MySQL? They are different products. (And why is Java relevant to the question?) Secondly, why auto-commit? Unless the constraint is deferred, you'll get an exception on insert not on commit. And why don't you just have a check constraint on UniqueID to stop it being above 10?

Comment: @AlexPoole I am using oracle. Thanks for pointing out. Java I mentioned because I wanted to highlight that parallel insertions can happen as the data is inserted via multiple nodes. In my testing i found out that inserting with auto-commit lead to much less collisions and hence less retries. I can have a check constraint but how do i make sure that every i don't  get duplicate uiniqueId for same ForeignId?

Comment: You can have a check constraint *and* your composite key.

Comment: Can you delete from table `B`?

Comment: ... and if you can, could you then add a row with unique ID 11, or would you re-use the removed ID? How are you calculating that value at the moment?

Comment: @AlexPoole I can delete from table B. In fact that is what I am doing if count is 11. And I cannot have the value 11. It needs to be 1-10 as this will be used as unique identifier in other places.

Comment: @AviralSrivastava - but will you delete at other times, or will the data stay there once successfully inserted? If you will delete, say from the middle of the unique IDs for a given foreign ID, can you re-use the unique ID - i.e. fill in the gap - on a later insert? Again, if you showed what you are doing now it might make things clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I cannot have the value 11. It needs to be 1-10

You can use a check constraint to prevent a value above 10 being added; as an outline (you might need to restrict to integers, for example; and use more meaningful names...):

```
create table a (
  id number,
  constraint a_pk primary key (id)
);

create table b (
  id number,
  data varchar2(10),
  foreign_id number not null,
  unique_id number not null,
  constraint b_pk primary key (id),
  constraint b_fk foreign key (foreign_id) references a (id),
  constraint b_uk unique (foreign_id, unique_id),
  constraint b_ch check (unique_id between 1 and 10)
);

insert into a (id) values (101);
insert into a (id) values (102);
```

Then you can insert up to 10:

```
insert into b (id, data, foreign_id, unique_id)
select 1, 'SomeData', 101, nvl(max(unique_id), 0) + 1
from b
where foreign_id = 101;

insert into b (id, data, foreign_id, unique_id)
select 2, 'SomeData', 101, nvl(max(unique_id), 0) + 1
from b
where foreign_id = 101;

...

insert into b (id, data, foreign_id, unique_id)
select 10, 'SomeData', 101, nvl(max(unique_id), 0) + 1
from b
where foreign_id = 101;
```

but trying to insert an 11th value fails:

```
insert into b (id, data, foreign_id, unique_id)
select 11, 'SomeData', 101, nvl(max(unique_id), 0) + 1
from b
where foreign_id = 101;

ORA-02290: check constraint (MY_SCHEMA.B_CH) violated
```

Trying to insert a duplicate will also still fail:

```
insert into b (id, data, foreign_id, unique_id)
values (11, 'SomeData', 101, 1);

ORA-00001: unique constraint (MYSCHEMA.B_UK) violated
```

But you have have the same 'unique' ID for different foreign keys:

```
insert into b (id, data, foreign_id, unique_id)
select 11, 'SomeData', 102, nvl(max(unique_id), 0) + 1
from b
where foreign_id = 102;

select * from b;

        ID DATA       FOREIGN_ID  UNIQUE_ID
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 SomeData          101          1
         2 SomeData          101          2
         3 SomeData          101          3
         4 SomeData          101          4
         5 SomeData          101          5
         6 SomeData          101          6
         7 SomeData          101          7
         8 SomeData          101          8
         9 SomeData          101          9
        10 SomeData          101         10
        11 SomeData          102          1
```

The way I'm getting the next unique ID for each foreign key means that if you delete a row you can't re-use its ID, unless the one you delete happens to be the highest value anyway. You can make the insert more sophisticated if you want to fill gaps, but you haven't shown how you're calculating that now, so you may not want to. A crude way, again:

```
delete from b where id = 3;

insert into b (id, data, foreign_id, unique_id)
values (12, 'SomeData', 101,
  (
    select min(n) from (select level as n from dual connect by level <= 10) x
    where not exists (
      select null from b where b.foreign_id = 101 and b.unique_id = x.n
    )
  )
);
```

If there are no gaps the scalar subquery gets `null`, so the insert fails on the not-null check.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1ce1e01635854cb15262bc02b174cc49)

---

If you wanted up to 10 values, but they could weren't restricted to 1-10, you could use a materialized view to keep the current count and have a check constraint against that not going above 10. That doesn't seem to be what you want here though.

Comment: How is this different from the solution that I have implemented apart from the fact that I won't have to do an extra delete if check constraint is violated.

Comment: You don't think that's a significant difference, particularly on the Java side? OK. Also you hadn't shown how you'd implemented it, only some bullet points. <shrug>

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky to implement.  One method is:

- Add a column to `A` which is the count of `B`s.
- Maintain this column with insert/update/delete triggers on `B`.
- Add a check constraint to `A` so the count never exceeds 10.

Another method is to pre-populate `B`.  Every time you insert an `A`, create 10 `B`s.  Be sure you have an "in_use" column in `B`.  Then your "inserts" into `B` via updates rather than `insert`.